# Record WLST Scripts for Adapter Settings for creating Outbound Connection Pools

Tags: python, weblogic, jython, wlst

I am new to the Record WLST Scripts tool.

I am trying to record within my Weblogic Administrative Console Settings for JmsAdapter to create a new Outbound Connection Pool, but the Record tool does not seem to be able to capture changes within adapter settings as the file is blank after the changes have been made.

Does anyone know why that is?

Is there a way to make the Record tool work for Adapter settings?

If not would anyone know the functions/directories needed in a WLST in order to create Outbound Connection Pools within JMSAdapter Settings?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Administration Console does not record WLST commands for the following (this is just a limitation of the recorder):

- Changes to the security data that is maintained by a security provider. For example, you cannot record the commands to add or remove users, roles, and policies.
- Changes to deployment plans.
- Runtime operations found on Control or Monitoring pages, such as starting and stopping applications or servers.

Here is a link on editing/creating a JMSAdapter: http://www.albinsblog.com/2013/03/creating-jms-adapter-connection-factory.html#.UcIQtPn05oE

Here is a link on connection pools, creating data sources etc: <strike>https://svn.java.net/svn/ci4fmw~ci4fmw/trunk/resourceScripts/createDS.py</strike>
http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=1400

Comment: The 2nd link si broken.

Comment: Updated - who knows how long some of the links will be around. The answer is still correct on what can and cannot be recorded